# jQuery Possible to use the .fadeTo() more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a script so that every time a specific button is pressed, I want to send out a warning message in a div tag. I decided to use the fadeTo because my div tag is inside a table and I dont want it to collapse. However, it seems like after the first press, any subsequent press will not work anymore. Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Here's my warning code:

```
$("#warning").html("The value is too low!").css('color','red').fadeTo(10000,0);
```

Comment: Well, first of all that "fadeTo" will fade to 0 opacity, thus hiding the div. Once hidden you do nothing to show it again, so it will stay hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of the `fadeTo`, the element's opacity is `0`. To re-start, reset the opacity back to 100, since otherwise it's trying to animate from `0` to `0`, which is...subtle to say the least. :-)

E.g.:

```
$("#warning")
    .html("The value is too low!")
    .stop()            // <=== New bit: Stop the animation if it's running
    .css({
      'opacity': 1,    // <=== New bit: Reset the opacity
      'color': 'red'
    })
    .fadeTo(10000,0);
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ozilof/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ozilof/2/edit) (uses one second rather than ten)

Comment: setting opacity to `1` is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the help. there seems to be an issue when I press it excessively that it most doesn't show up anymore but if I do it conservatively its ok. The same goes for the live example. But it might be just my comp.

Comment: @Dan You have to add `stop()` before `fadeTo` like in my downvoted solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to show the div again:

```
$("#warning").show().html("The value is too low!").css('color','red').fadeTo(10000,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use opacity animation instead:

```
$("#warning").html("The value is too low!").css({
    color : 'red',
    opacity : 1
}).stop().animate({
    opacity : 0
}, 1000);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/SDWmn/1/